How to mix 2 audio files into one in ffmpeg-go?
Using ffmpeg-go, I am trying to trim and mix (overlay) two audio files together. Currently I have this code:
func AssebmleAudio(music, effect string, userId int) {

    outputFilePath := filepath.Join(utils.GetRoot(), "users", fmt.Sprintf("%d", userId), "audio.mp3")

    musicStream := Trim(ffmpeg_go.Input(music), 60)
    effectStream := Trim(ffmpeg_go.Input(effect), 60)
    Mix(musicStream, effectStream).Output(outputFilePath).Run()

}

// Mixes specified user audio and vinyl audio asset
func Mix(music, effect *ffmpeg_go.Stream) *ffmpeg_go.Stream {
    return ffmpeg_go.Filter(
        []*ffmpeg_go.Stream{
            music,
            effect,
        },
        "amix",
        ffmpeg_go.Args{"inputs=2:duration=longest:dropout_transition=2"},
    )
}


func Trim(music *ffmpeg_go.Stream, duration int) *ffmpeg_go.Stream {
    return music.Trim(ffmpeg_go.KwArgs{"duration": fmt.Sprintf("%d", duration)})
}

However, AssembleAudio while tested yields the following error:
panic: encountered trim with multiple outgoing edges with same upstream label ; a 'split'' filter is probably required
I found solutions for plain ffmpeg, I also found this question, but I have no idea how to do this in go.
